MS Graph InteractiveBrowserCredential , Is a Client ID registered in Azure Portal really necessary?
I work with an organization that has a MS 365 tenant. We have Dot Net applications that currently use a different authentication scheme, and we want to rework them to authenticate against MS 365. Due to our organizational structure, we don't have access to the Azure Portal so getting a client id for my application(s) requires reaching out far beyond my department.
I have done some experiments with MS Graph, and I am able to authenticate and get enough profile information to do what I need to do. But I'm doing all that without a client id. Everything I'm able to find says that this method is acceptable for development but not production, but I still don't fully understand why. Am I creating some security risk? For the tenant? Other applications?
I don't need to access or manipulate anything in the tenant, I would just take something like 'mail' or 'UPN' and authorize against an internal database for access.
Anyone comments or advise is appreciated.
Here is the basic code that works for me.
    static async Task<GraphServiceClient> CreateGraphClient()
    {
        // Create an instance of the GraphServiceClient using Azure Identity
        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };
        var ibcOptions = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions();
        ibcOptions.TenantId = "xxxx";
        ibcOptions.DisableAutomaticAuthentication = true;
        var interactiveBrowserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential( ibcOptions );
        var result = interactiveBrowserCredential.Authenticate();
        var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveBrowserCredential);
        return graphServiceClient;
    }


It is recommended to pass clientID. When you use a client ID, you're essentially telling Azure AD which application is requesting authentication and what permissions it needs. This allows Azure AD to manage and enforce security policies, such as access control, consent management, and auditing.


Note that: Client ID is necessary to authenticate your app with Microsoft Entra ID and access Microsoft Graph API.


Yes, it is possible to authenticate and get profile information without a client ID, but not recommended for production use.
Without a client ID, it is using the default client ID. This means that you may be creating a security risk for your organization by allowing unauthorized access to your tenant.

Hence obtain a client ID for the Microsoft Entra ID application by registering it with User.Read delegated Microsoft Graph API permission to get the signed in user details:
Add http://localhost as redirect URL in Mobile and desktop applications platform and enable mobile and desktop flows as YES:


Modify the code to pass the ClientID of the Microsoft Entra ID application and to fetch the user details:
public class GraphClientHelper
{
    public static async Task<GraphServiceClient> CreateGraphClientAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var ibcOptions = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
            {
                TenantId = "TenantID", 
                ClientId = "ClientID", // Replace with your Client ID
                DisableAutomaticAuthentication = false, 
                RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost") 
            };

            var interactiveBrowserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(ibcOptions);
            var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveBrowserCredential, new[] { "User.Read" });
            return graphServiceClient;
        }
        catch (AuthenticationFailedException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Authentication failed: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var graphClient = await GraphClientHelper.CreateGraphClientAsync();

            var user = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"User: {user.DisplayName}, Email: {user.Mail}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}


Reference:
Choose a Microsoft Graph authentication provider - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft

Thanks Rukmini. I do understand about application registration and client IDs, unfortunately getting my application registered is something of a challenge in my particular position.
But my question is this: What's the difference between the "default Client ID" and a newly created one with explicit permissions? My application would not access anything inside MS 365 once it retrieves the profile attributes. And you still need to provide credentials.
How does accessing something that exists create a security risk? Can the default ID be modified? Turned Off?

The "default Client ID" used when none is provided is associated with Microsoft's built-in applications for general use. While it allows you to retrieve profile attributes, it doesn’t provide fine-grained control over permissions, auditing, or access management specific to your application

Using the default client ID in production can be risky because of Lack of Control and Audit and Monitoring

When you register your own client ID, you explicitly define the permissions your app requires, ensuring better security practices. This also helps your organization manage and monitor app activities, such as detecting anomalies or revoking access if necessary.

I've read all your comments, and I understand what you are saying. I am still skeptical about this being a security concern in my situation being that I just want to authenticate, perhaps the default Client ID may have more permissions than I actually need.
In any case given what you've said and how I understand it, it probably isn't worth trying to short circuit the situation. I'll just have to hope that MS 365 administrators in my organization will understand the need for providing this service to developers and make it accessible. Thanks for taking the time to follow up!
